# Formula to Autofill 2D matrix in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to create a formula to fill in a 2D matrix of arbitrary length (8x8 in my case) with numbers starting from 1 and going to 64.

I can do this manually however I want to create a formula that does this for me, like so:

[[image: Click here to see a picture of what I mean]]

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your question isn't really clear now, do you want to have the same formula in all cells, recognizing the shape of the area with formula and filling automatically, or can you also use some helper cell where you enter size of your matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after but if you want one formula that would work for every cell I've thought of this:

`=ROW()*COLUMNS(matrix)-(COLUMNS(matrix)-COLUMN())`
where *matrix* is a named range that defines the width of your desired matrix. Then you fill this formula into every cell in the matrix.